# Upgrade NodeJS leaves me with two versions

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

I attempted an upgrade of Node using brew, but after the upgrade I am left with two versions. How can I get rid of the old one?

When I run `brew upgrade node` It tells me that 0.12.7 is already installed.
However if I run `node -v`

I get the version 0.10.26. It appears that I now have two versions installed.
How can I remove the oldest version?

Comment: `brew cleanup node`?

Comment: Gave that a try, but didn't work for me

Comment: If switch to 0.12.7 and after cleanup?

Comment: Why not using [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to delete your node binary folder which will contain those two files:

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node`

And then run install again:

`brew install node`

Be sure to backup your folder PRIOR to doing this in the case it freaks out.

Also - from personal experience, homebrew creates more problems that it solves. Just use the Node.js install script on their website.

Comment: Ended up taking you advice about not using brew. Works after I got it from the website

Comment: Ya - I wish homebrew worked well for Node.js but have always had issues. Whenever I use the native installer, it works like a charm. Glad you got it to work.

Comment: Yep. Thanks for your help